# How to suppress all messages in knitr/ Rmarkdown?

Tags: knitr, r-markdown

I have used `dplyr` for some of the analyses and for a particular code it takes about 30 seconds to complete the operation. In the resulting HTML I get a very long output of something like this (reproducing last few lines):

```
|================================================ |100% ~0 s remaining     
|================================================ |100% ~0 s remaining     
Completed after 35 s
```

I don't want this to show in the output. How can I suppress this? Is there anythink in the global chunk options of knitr that could stop these messages

Comment: Have you tried `opts_knit$set(progress=FALSE)`? Also, there was an [issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/428) regarding this that appears to be closed in June. You can possibly work around with the `min_time` parameter (of `do`, if you're using `do`).

Comment: how can I specify `min_time` in `do`? There is nothing about it in help. If I use it as an argument it gives `Error: Arguments to do() must either be all named or all unnamed`

Comment: It looks like the issue closing did not mean that the parameter made it into any of the releases. `do` is calling `p <- progress_estimated(n * m, min_time = 2)` which is what is probably causing your issue. Perhaps try to re-open the issue?

Comment: Oh. I don't use Github so that's not possible for me. Thanks for your comments. Regarding the `Progress=FALSE`, I have global chunk options of the document defined in the first chunk as `opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, cache=TRUE, fig.align='center', fig.path='figure/')`. Can I just add `Progress=FALSE` in it? Or do I have to explicitly write `opts_knit$set(progress=FALSE)` under it? This might be a stupid question but I am new so please bear with me.

Comment: @hrbrmstr The progress bar came from dplyr instead of knitr, so `knitr::opts_knit$set(progress=FALSE)` will not be able to suppress it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want the chunk option `results='hide'` for that particular code chunk only.

````
```{r results='hide'}
# do your dplyr computation here
```
````

Answer (score -1):

or do message='hide' or if you have a warning you do waring='hide'.

Depends on what is showing but if you look up chunk options in google you can find which one will hide what you are wanting to hide.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk-options), message and warning should be logical (TRUE or FALSE).